# is it important to set system hardware clock from the system OS

Tags: linux, rhel, time, ntp

*we have redhat 7.2 machines ( some of them are physical machines , and some of them are VM machines )*

After my client computers have synchronized with the NTP server,
we are thinking to set the system hardware clock from the system (OS) time by using the following command

```
/sbin/hwclock --systohc
```

**is it really important to set sync the HW clock with OS clock?**

note - This command can be added as a cron job or a script in cron.daily to keep the hardware clock synced with the system time

Comment: According to Kusalananda's answer you apparently don't have to worry about this. The reason why the system hardware clock needs to to be updated in the *first place*, or if it is "important", is that the hardware clock is the only time source available when the machine is turned on. ntpd refuses to reset the clock if the clock has drifted too far off, which can easily happen if you don't regularly write the correct time to the RTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [a blog post](https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/04/how-ntp-sync-with-hwclock-at-boot-startup.html):

> In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, the `hwclock` command was run automatically on every system shutdown or reboot, but it is not in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. When the system clock is synchronized by the Network Time Protocol (NTP) or Precision Time Protocol (PTP), **the kernel automatically synchronizes the hardware clock to the system clock every 11 minutes**.

It therefore seems unnecessary to run the `hwclock` manually (or via a cron job) on your system.

The blog post also mention that one should set `SYNC_HWCLOCK=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/ntpdate`. It is however unclear whether this is already the default or not.

The RedHat Customer Portal [contains similar information](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-configuring_the_date_and_time-hwclock):

> Either you can set the hardware clock to the current system time by using this command:
>
> ```
> hwclock --systohc
> ```
>
> Note that if you use NTP, the hardware clock is automatically synchronized to the system clock every 11 minutes, and this command is useful only at boot time to get a reasonable initial system time.

Both of the links above were found by searching DuckDuckGo for "[ntp hwclock](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ntp+hwclock)".

Comment: in our machines  ( redhat 7.2 ) - /etc/sysconfig/ntpdate not include the line - SYNC_HWCLOCK=yes  , so do you recommended to add the SYNC_HWCLOCK=yes in this file?

Comment: @yael Since I don't run RedHat, I can't say that I know if you need it. That blog post also does not make it certain that it's needed on a 7.x system or not.  The RedHat document does not mention that configuration at all. It seems likely that setting the option in the file will cause `ntpdate` to sync the time to the HW clock when it runs. The NTP server then does this anyway every 11 minutes.

Comment: ok , btw can you help me with my post on - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538575/machines-are-with-time-gap-in-spite-chronyd-service-is-running